# Как сделать правильно при задании timeoutsession для facelets после входа в аккаунт?

Tags: java, jsf

Я создал отдельный класc. Но он отрабатывает даже если я еще не залогинился. То есть, я захожу на страницу где поля ввода логина и пароля. И получается чрез 5 секунд я уже не могу залогиниться и показывается следующая ошибка HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser. Надо чтобы setMaxInactiveInterval задавался только после входа в аккаунт. Помогите пожалуйста((

```
public class HttpSessionTimeoutListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        String strLogout = Optional.ofNullable(SystemProperties.get("logout_time")).orElseGet(() -> "5");

        try {
            System.out.println(new Integer(strLogout));
            httpSessionEvent.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(new Integer(strLogout));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            getLogger().error("Invalid parameter value");
        }
    }

    private Logger getLogger() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpSessionTimeoutListener.class);
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event){}
}

 <listener>
    <listener-class>com.bifit.cms.utils.HttpSessionTimeoutListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```